# Hodge Star and $\partial$-Harmonicity

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a complex manifold of complex dimension $n$ endowed with a hermitian metric. It is clear that as the Hodge star is invertible and commutes with the Laplacian $\Delta = d d^* + d^* d$, the star gives an isomorphism between $d$-harmonic $(p,q)$-forms and harmonic $(n-q, n-p)$-forms.

I'm trying to understand how the Hodge star interacts with $\bar\partial$-harmonic forms (this would be trivial if I were to assume that $X$ is Kahler as in this case all of the Laplacians coincide).
In particular, I wonder if $\bar\partial$-harmonic forms are mapped to $\partial$-harmonic forms. I think there should be an isomorphism $*: \mathcal{H}_{\bar\partial}^{p,q}(X) \to \mathcal{H}_\partial^{n-q, n-p}(X)$ but am having a hard time showing this.

Comment: Can you write $\partial^*\partial(\ast\alpha)$ in terms of $\bar{\partial}$ and $\bar{\partial}^*$?